# Change the value of a dataframe column to the value of a second column conditional on the value of a third column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean-logic

I have data with current names of companies, old names, and the date of name changes. It looks like this:

| name | former_name1 | name_change_date1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ACMAT CORP | nan | NaT |
| ACME ELECTRIC CORP | nan | NaT |
| ACME UNITED CORP | nan | NaT |
| COLUMBIA ACORN TRUST | LIBERTY ACORN TRUST | 2003-10-20 |
| MULTIGRAPHICS INC | AM INTERNATIONAL INC | 1997-03-17 |
| MILLER LLOYD I III | nan | NaT |
| AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC | nan | NaT |
| ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY, INC. | ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC | 2005-04-01 |
| BK Technologies Corp | BK Technologies, Inc. | 2019-03-28 |

I want to figure out what the name of each company was at a particular date. Let's say I want to figure out the name of a company as of January 1st 2002. Then I could create a new column called say,  `edited_name`, which would contain the current name of the company *unless* the company has changed names since 1/1/2002, in which case it would contain the historical name (i.e. `former_name1`) of the company. So the output should look something like this:

| name | former_name1 | name_change_date1 | edited_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACMAT CORP | nan | NaT | ACMAT CORP |
| ACME ELECTRIC CORP | nan | NaT | ACME ELECTRIC CORP |
| ACME UNITED CORP | nan | NaT | ACME UNITED CORP |
| COLUMBIA ACORN TRUST | LIBERTY ACORN TRUST | 2003-10-20 | LIBERTY ACORN TRUST |
| MULTIGRAPHICS INC | AM INTERNATIONAL INC | 1997-03-17 | MULTIGRAPHICS INC |
| MILLER LLOYD I III | nan | NaT | MILLER LLOYD I III |
| AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC | nan | NaT | AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC |
| ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY, INC. | ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC | 2005-04-01 | ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC |
| BK Technologies Corp | BK Technologies, Inc. | 2019-03-28 | BK Technologies, Inc. |

In Stata (with which I am much more familiar) this could be easily accomplished with:

```
gen edited_name = name
replace edited_name = former_name1 if name_change_date_1 > date("2002-01-01", "YMD") & name_change_date_1 != .
```

Unfortunately I am at a loss of how to accomplish this in Python/Pandas.

Data:

```
{'name': ['ACMAT CORP', 'ACME ELECTRIC CORP', 'ACME UNITED CORP', 'COLUMBIA ACORN TRUST',
          'MULTIGRAPHICS INC', 'MILLER LLOYD I III', 'AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC',
          'ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY, INC.', 'BK Technologies Corp'],
 'former_name1': [nan, nan, nan, 'LIBERTY ACORN TRUST', 'AM INTERNATIONAL INC', nan, nan,
                  'ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC', 'BK Technologies, Inc.'],
 'name_change_date1': [NaT, NaT, NaT, '2003-10-20', '1997-03-17', NaT, NaT,
                       '2005-04-01', '2019-03-28']}
```

Comment: Can you provide data in a format that we can copy?

Comment: Also do you consider that companies always existed? What should happen if you request the name at, say, date '1800-01-01'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select values depending on if a name change occurred or not:

```
import numpy as np
df['edited_name'] = np.where(df['name_change_date1'].notna() & 
                             df['name_change_date1'].gt(pd.to_datetime('1/1/2002')), 
                             df['former_name1'], df['name'])
```

or with [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df['edited_name'] = df['name'].mask(df['name_change_date1'].notna() & 
                                    df['name_change_date1'].gt(pd.to_datetime('1/1/2002')), 
                                    df['former_name1'])
```

Output:

```
                               name                  former_name1  \
0                        ACMAT CORP                           NaN   
1                ACME ELECTRIC CORP                           NaN   
2                  ACME UNITED CORP                           NaN   
3              COLUMBIA ACORN TRUST           LIBERTY ACORN TRUST   
4                 MULTIGRAPHICS INC          AM INTERNATIONAL INC   
5                MILLER LLOYD I III                           NaN   
6  AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC                           NaN   
7    ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY, INC.  ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC   
8              BK Technologies Corp         BK Technologies, Inc.   

  name_change_date1                       edited_name  
0               NaT                        ACMAT CORP  
1               NaT                ACME ELECTRIC CORP  
2               NaT                  ACME UNITED CORP  
3        2003-10-20               LIBERTY ACORN TRUST  
4        1997-03-17                 MULTIGRAPHICS INC  
5               NaT                MILLER LLOYD I III  
6               NaT  AFFILIATED COMPUTER SERVICES INC  
7        2005-04-01      ADAMS RESOURCES & ENERGY INC  
8        2019-03-28             BK Technologies, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'fname':[np.nan, 'h', 's', np.nan], 'dc':[np.nan, '2003-10-20', '1997-03-17', np.nan]})
df['dc'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dc'])
df['nname'] = df['fname'][df['dc']>'1/1/2002']
res = df['name'][df['nname'].isna()]
temp = df['fname'][df['nname'].notna()]
res = res.append(temp)
df['res']=res
```

output:

[image]